# Old file is being downloaded from web server when browsing from client

Tags: iis, web-server, windows-server-2012-r2, cache, isp

I am facing a new strange problem while downloading files from web server. I am using windows server 2012.

I will explain the problem with example.

I have a text file (update.txt) in my server, to which I am writing some info about the currently available downloads.

Now I will update the update.txt. But when I download that file, old txt is being downloaded instead of new one.  I have tried to download using Chrome, Firefox and IE with clearing history but the problem is not solved. I have deleted the file from server and then tried to download but still old file downloaded.

When I change the Internet to another ISP the problem is solved.

So what causes this error?
Whether ISP keep the cache of downloads? 
Or Is this the error of web server ?

Comment: If you are accessing the file from behind a proxy or firewall it is possible that those devices cache the file.

Comment: @humble.adm1n How can clear/request to clear those cache once I update file ?

Comment: That depends on the type of your firewall/proxy. Your best bet would be to ask the responsible admin.

Comment: Is there a load balancer? Second web server?

Answer (score -1):

on a linux server with apache2, i would make a .htaccess file with:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\update.txt>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

if you use apache2 on windows give it a try.